# HTML header is not coming out at the correct width

Tags: html, css

Here's the plan I had for my page:

- Body width x height of  600 x 800 pixels; no padding, so that elements inside it can fit snugly against the wall if they have no margin.
- 3 elements inside the body: A header, main content and footer, which are deemed classes (because I'm going to use the same layout on multiple pages of my website).
- The width of the 3 elements will each be 598 pixels, the margin will be 0 pixels, and the border will be 1 pixel, so that they fit perfectly inside the body. The borders will be dashed to add visual context.
- The 3 elements' will divide up the height of the body through respective pixels of 150, 500, and 150. Their 1-pixel bottom/top borders will overlap. So the vertical space of the page will be a 1-pixel border at the top, 148 pixels of space, 1 pixel of border, 499 pixels of space, 1 pixel of border, 149 pixels of space and finally 1 pixel of border at the bottom.

If you can, please explain to me where I went wrong in the HTML logic of my implementation. My header is not the correct width when I preview the page. (Obviously my page is going to look colorful and dynamic when I finish it. Right now I'm just trying to get the layout right.)

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>div practice</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            padding: 0px;
            height: 800px;
            width: 600px;
        }
        .header
        {
            margin: 0px;
            border: 1px dashed;
            width: 598 px;
            height: 148px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        } 
        .mainContent
        {
            margin: 0px;
            border: 1px dashed;
            width: 598px;
            height: 500px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 148px;
            left: 0px;  
        }
        .footer
        {
            margin: 0px;
            border: 1px dashed;
            width: 598px;
            height: 148px;
            position: absolute; 
            top: 648px;
            left: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
     <div class="header">
        <p>This is where the header goes</p>
     </div>
     <div class="mainContent">
        <p>This where the main content goes</p>  
     </div>
     <div class="footer">
        <p>This is where the footer goes</p>     
     </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1st, please never put a height for your content, this is not good at all and will make problems for you.

Comment: What problem, if I may ask?

Comment: because if you have contents that will exceed the height you defined, it will go over your styling.  See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/salota8550/F7rF6/

Answer (score 2):

In your `.header` styles change `width: 598 px;` to `width: 598px;`

`598 px` is not a valid property value so it is ignored.  Remove the space and it should work as expected.

Also, if you add this line of code:

```
*, *:before, *:after { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This will change the box model so that padding and borders are subtracted from the specified width rather than added to it.  It's a popular technique nowadays as it makes the math less of a headache and is conducive to responsive design.  With this style you can define your header with `width: 600px;` and still add whatever `border` and `padding` you want without affecting the width.

Answer (score 0):

As a plan I would prefer the following:

1) make your `body` width 100%

```
body{
 width: 100%;
}
```

2) add an `outterWrapper` div to contain all your page elements.

```
.outterWrapper{
    width: 600px; // your page width;
    margin: 0 auto; // to center in page
    border: 1px solid #000; // if you need a border
}
```

3) Start style your header, content, footer divs

```
.header, .footer, .content{
 width: 100%;
 padding: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.header, .footer{
 background-color: #cfe09b;
}
.footer{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.content{
 background-color: #89ccca;
}
```

You can see what I mean here >> http://jsfiddle.net/salota8550/EPsk2/